# Whats the difference between Object Role Modeling and Object-relational mapping?

Tags: object, orm, role, database-design, object-role-modeling

I have learn about Object role modeling but not about Object-relational mapping and I want to know if they are two ways of doing the same thing and what are the pros and cons? To me Object role modeling makes a lot more sense. Could you make a brief but easy to understand comparison if they can be compared. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

Object Role Modeling: software modeling notation to, specially, define domain models. You can think of this language as an alternative to using UML class diagrams to design your database. More info here: http://www.orm.net/

Object-relational mapping: a set of strategies to bridge the gap between object-oriented programs and relational databases. It aims to allow the persistent storage of objects in a relational database structure

Answer (score 5):

Object Role Modeling was invented by a team at Control Data around 1973, and named by Falkenberg. It is a modeling method rooted in linguistic analysis, and was formalised as a first-order logic by Terry Halpin, see http://orm.net. ORM is thus the **original** user of the acronym. ORM and related modeling languages are distinguished by being **attribute-free**. These languages contain only objects and object types (kinds of things), facts and fact types (relationships between individual things) and constraints (rules about what things and relationships may exist). No relationship has the master-slave characteristic like entity-attribute - this is a notion that only arises during physical mapping, as it's irrelevant to the underlying semantics of the domain.

Object Relational Mapping (which I always write O/RM) is a name for a method or family of tools that help translate data between relational form and object-oriented form. Both these forms use aggregate or composite things based on attributes (entity/attribute or object/attribute), but the principles for aggregation differ between the two approaches, so the same underlying semantics results in different data structures; hence the need for tools to help automate the translation. Furthermore, in ER or O-O analysis, the need to make early decisions about which things are objects/entities and which are attributes is forced, and this gives rise to a whole class of modeling errors that simply does not occur with ORM.

Of course, both relational and o-o models can be automatically derived from an ORM model, and the mapping between the derived forms is also automatic and painless. I suppose that's not done more often because it would make life too easy.

Answer (score 3):

You are comapring Apples to Oranges.
Object Relational Mapping  is all about trying to overcome the impedance msimatch between the object world and relational databases.

Activerecord for example is a ORM that wraps a row in a database.
Hibernate is another popular ORM

Just google for ORM wikipedia explains it much better

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch

Comment: Which one is Object Realtional Modelling  supposed to be?

Comment: The OP already understands Object Role Modelling and hence no point in explaining that.I explained what object relational mapping is and where he can find more answers .I dont understand why i was downvoted

Comment: I am sorry that doesn't really make any sense. I didn't ever mention 'Object Realtional Modelling' I said Object-relational mapping and Object role modeling, how I am I spose to understand what you are talking about. I have googled them but I want to know the difference from people that use the methords.

Comment: You were downvoted because before you edited your post had so many typos it didn't even make sense.